# is there any way to edit data in custom Tree (UL , Li) populated by loop through data returned from sql query (Ado.net)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, ado.net

I need to build contracts structure in the company, so I build 3 tables (companies, contracts, details) that work fine with the bussiness of the company, i didn't used the tree view , i used a bootstrap tabs with custom tree, is there any way to edit each node of the tree alone

--- The tree looks like the attached pictureٍ [image]